# SQL query table inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a issue where the SKU doesn't match the correct lines via the color. The csv rows / items do not match and there seems to be a lot of duplicates the DIM_1_UPR field in the csv needs to match the SKU, BARCODE, and VENDOR_SKU fields. I think I messed up my inner join.

Here is a screen shot with one item.. you can see it is showing 288 rows. It is duplicating the same thing  multiple times and the SKU / VENDOR_SKU / BARCODE basically everything from USR_MAG_ITEM_EXP doesn't match or line up correctly with the rest of the table :

[image]

Do I have to do all keys or can I just use the one ITEM_NO?

[Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqm3Z.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
SELECT    

dbo.IM_PRC.ITEM_NO, dbo.IM_PRC.REG_PRC, dbo.IM_PRC.PRC_1, 
dbo.IM_PRC.PRC_2,dbo.IM_ITEM.CATEG_COD,
dbo.IM_ITEM.SUBCAT_COD, dbo.IM_ITEM.STAT, dbo.IM_ITEM.LST_COST, 
dbo.IM_ITEM.USER_MAG_NAME, dbo.IM_INV_CELL.LOC_ID, 
dbo.IM_INV_CELL.DIM_1_UPR, dbo.IM_INV_CELL.MIN_QTY, dbo.IM_INV_CELL.MAX_QTY, 
dbo.IM_INV_CELL.QTY_ON_HND, dbo.USR_MAG_ITEM_EXP.SKU, 
dbo.USR_MAG_ITEM_EXP.VENDOR_SKU,
dbo.USR_MAG_ITEM_EXP.BARCOD

FROM dbo.IM_PRC
INNER JOIN dbo.IM_ITEM ON dbo.IM_PRC.ITEM_NO = dbo.IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO 
INNER JOIN dbo.IM_INV_CELL ON dbo.IM_INV_CELL.ITEM_NO = dbo.IM_PRC.ITEM_NO
INNER JOIN dbo.USR_MAG_ITEM_EXP ON dbo.USR_MAG_ITEM_EXP.ITEM_NO = 
dbo.IM_PRC.ITEM_NO

WHERE dbo.IM_INV_CELL.LOC_ID IN ('01', '03', '11', '12', '14', '23') and 
dbo.IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO = 'grohrostbk'
ORDER BY IM_INV_CELL.LOC_ID ASC
```

Edit : so doing a full outter join and adding the extra syntax for joining that aaron suggested gave me no duplicates! But

how do I include our parent products that do not have a color or add a empty DIM_1_UPR for example I want the top line to be included in the major sheet - SELECT top 5 item_no, name, sku, DIM_1_UPR, vendor_sku FROM dbo.USR_MAG_ITEM_EXP WHERE ITEM_NO = 'grohrostbk' screen: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsZ49.jpg)

Comment: Please don't upload image of data. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 You also really need to use aliases. 3 and 4 part naming in the list of columns has been deprecated for a while now.

Comment: I don't know SQL and this is going to be a one time use thing

Comment: OK. Still need real details here instead of images. It looks like your tables have custom datatype for a lot of stuff and there is a huge lack of normalization. You have what is known as "repeating groups" which violates 1NF and is a real pain to work with.

Comment: As a shot in the dark I would say your queries are not correct because you have composite keys in these tables and you are joining on only parts of the key. Consider if you had a table of names with two columns as the primary key (firstname and lastname). But you joined to another table on only the first name. You would get johnny smith and johnny doe for each row. Join on the ENTIRE key and your query will likely get what you want.

Comment: @SeanLange Thx I updated the image links it kept saying I had code in the post idk why. What do you need to know? Like I said i have no clue what 1NF is consider me a 100% noob. the 3 tables have multiple gold keys so that means there are multiple primary keys i need to inner join?

Comment: No problem everybody was a 100% noob at one point. :) To be clear there are NOT multiple primary keys. Any table can have one and only one primary key. But that key can consist of multiple columns. Those gold keys indicate that you have a composite primary key. And you are joining on only a portion of the key.

Comment: If I go to the Tables folder then select dbo.IM_PRC for example there is ITEM_NO (PK,FK,T_ITEM_NO(varchar20)), not null) then below that is LOCI_ID (PK, T_LOC_ID(varchar(10)),not null) then same thing with DIM_1_UPR, DIM_2_UPR, DIM_3_UPR all have PK next to it. Does that mean  there are multiple primary keys i need to inner join? All 3 tables do have ITEM_NO as a gold key and PK next to it that is how I wanted to connect them right?

Comment: Again there is no such thing as multiple primary keys. But I can't answer that because I don't know your data or the structures. It is possible you need only a portion of the key depending on how this was put together. I wouldn't be surprised if it is pretty sloppy given the structure that we can see.

Comment: What does `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.USR_MAG_ITEM_EXP WHERE ITEM_NO = 'grohrostbk'` look like?  You mentioned the results looked good before adding the final join, so a peek at the final table might help us see the issue.

Comment: @AaronDietz https://ibb.co/cVwFrU

Comment: Change the join to this and see what happens `INNER JOIN dbo.USR_MAG_ITEM_EXP ON dbo.USR_MAG_ITEM_EXP.ITEM_NO = 
dbo.IM_PRC.ITEM_NO AND dbo.USR_MAG_ITEM_EXP.DIM_1_UPR = dbo.IM_INV_CELL.DIM_1_UPR`

Comment: The reason I suggest the above is because if you look in that table,  the `ITEM_NO` repeats on each line with a different `DIM_1_UPR`.  If you include the `DIM_1_UPR` as part of the join, it won't duplicate out those rows.  Like Sean said, it's a shot in the dark to know if that will work, but ultimately you will want to include more columns (parts of the key) in the join, and it looks like that is one you will definitely want.

Comment: That makes sense I have all the correct columns that I will require so my select is WHERE is correct but I only need DIM_1_UPR the other two I don't need- Got a error though what is the FROM? dbo.IM_PRC?

Comment: @AaronDietz the DIM_1_UPR for this specific product "GROHROSTBK" Should just have 3 colors ( BK/BLACK, BK/ARCTIC BLUE, and BK/RED per store location so it is repeating multiple times.

Comment: Keep the rest of your query, just paste my comment join over the current join to `dbo.USR_MAG_ITEM_EXP`

Comment: Or just add `AND dbo.USR_MAG_ITEM_EXP.DIM_1_UPR = dbo.IM_INV_CELL.DIM_1_UPR` to the end of that join.  Whatever is easier.  We're just adding that extra condition. (joins can have as many conditions as you want)

Comment: @AaronDietz ohh its looking much better now but there still are 4 duplicates but the Barcode worked and the SKU's match!

Comment: Good deal.  Unfortunately that's pretty much the best I can do from the screens... Nothing else is showing as an obvious duplicate source.  I'll check back tomorrow and see if there is anything else I can add to help you out.

Comment: @AaronDietz this is awesome but there are 4 of each line not sure why?  here is a screen https://ibb.co/jd1Aap

Comment: @AaronDietz one more thing is how do I include our parent products that do not have a color or add a empty DIM_1_UPR for example I want the top line to be included in the major sheet - SELECT top 5 item_no, name, sku, DIM_1_UPR, vendor_sku FROM dbo.USR_MAG_ITEM_EXP WHERE ITEM_NO = 'grohrostbk'  screen: https://ibb.co/k9wMgU

Comment: would that be a full outer join? To list rows that do not have matches? When I changed my code to FULL OUTER JOIN i had zero duplicates but i'm still missing the parent products

Comment: @AaronDietz Edit : so doing a full outter join and adding the extra syntax for joining that aaron suggested gave me no duplicates! But how do I include our parent products that do not have a color or add a empty DIM_1_UPR for example I want the top line to be included in the major sheet that includes the * and vendorsku screen: ibb.co/k9wMgU

Comment: @AaronDietz Also when I do a FULL outer Join the table is larger but it is showing items that do not match which is what I want I need every single product even if there are NULL columns expample no USER_MAG_ITEM_EXP.name.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the screen shot [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLl23.jpg)  you can see that the first LINE has a DIM_1_UPR of "*" and a  VENDOR_SKU of "HROSTBK" but when I run the main joined sheet I do not see this LINE because it has a * and no color. Any thoughts on how to include it?